# google real time data of rolling 30 mins at interval of 5 min

Tags: time-series, google-analytics-api, series, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-expressions

I have google real time data of rolling 30 mins at interval of 5 min. 
how can i get data of 5 min each, share logic for the same thanks

i have data like
01 05 am.............

```
10 00 am  20 user(data of 30 mins i.e 9 30 am to 10 00 am)
10 05 am  25 user(data of 30 mins i.e 9 35 am to 10 05 am)
10 10 am  19 user(data of 30 mins i.e 9 45 am to 10 15 am)
10 15 am  26 user(data of 30 mins i.e 9 50 am to 10 20 am)
10 20 am  17 user(data of 30 mins i.e 9 55 am to 10 25 am)
```

and so on on interval of 5 mins.

now i have figure out user which were there from 10 05 am to 10 10 am i.e of 5 mins but i have data of 30 mins which is refreshed on 5 mins interval.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @dalmto Hope now it simplifies the question

Comment: How exactly do you intend to figure out which users where online?   I am sorry i still dont understand what your problem is.

Comment: 1.google analytic real-time  gives Last 30 min data for active user.
2.data needed to me is of last 5 mins.
3.so figured out than i can store data every 5 mins interval
4.Then i may have series of data which will be having count of user of last 30 mins each.

Comment: Yes but users are unidentifiable in Google analytics data.   There is no way for you to know who it was you just know there was 26 users during that time.

Comment: i need count  of users of last 5 mins

Comment: It show that there were 26 user in last 30min but i need to know users in last 5 min

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The [realtime.get](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get) method does not accept a start and end date it returns what there is.

The Google Analytics real time api gives you information about the current activity on your website.  This data is like all other google analytics data.  It is anonymous there is no way of knowing who these users were.

My experience its the data for around the last 15 minutes. I suggest you try adding the rt:minutesAgo dimension in order to see how long ago these users where online.

You need to remember this is a Beta API it is not a full fully functional api.

Comment: Well its not going to limit it to 5 minutes there is just no way to do that.

Comment: There can be any mathematical  equation which can help to solve this as 
 the data is in series ?

Comment: How google analytics will only return it does not have the limit it by time frame.

Comment: thanks @dalmto trying to find the result from mathematical solutions.